# How to render list inline with reverse floating and overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem that I don't know if is possible to solve with html/css only. I could add some javascript but only if needed.
Basically, I have a list of items like this:

```
<div class="itemlist">
    <span class="item">item 1</span>
    <span class="item">item 2</span>
    <span class="item">item 3</span>
    <span class="item">item 4</span>
</div>
```

I want to render the list on one row, with all the items floating to right (but in the same order), with a hidden overflow. So it will looks like this:

`|                      item 1   item 2   item 3   item 4|`

or like this

`|1   item 2   item 3   item 4   item 5   item 6   item 7|`

I'm trying using `overflow: hidden` on the `.itemlist` but it doesn't work. Also, the `float: right` reverse the items, so I cannot have what I want.

I'm really new with css, and in this site, too... is it possible to achieve that result with html and css only? Can you give me a hint on what I should look for?

Comment: Thank you, I don't really care about old browsers, so it's fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox and justify the content to the end:

```css
.itemlist {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.item {
  white-space:nowrap;  /* this is to stop flexbox making the content wrap to fit the width */
}
```

```html
<div class="itemlist">
  <span class="item">item 1</span>
  <span class="item">item 2</span>
  <span class="item">item 3</span>
  <span class="item">item 4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is definitely what I was searching for. I didn't try flexbox, thank you!